# What GraphQL Transform directives does AWS Amplify support with Aurora? (ex: @searchable @versioned)

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-aurora-serverless

I saw that Amplify has [improved support for @auth and @connection when used with Aurora instead of Dynamo](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-amplify-announces-new-amazon-aurora-serverless-and-graphql-transform-features-for-building-aws-appsync-apis/); however, it's hard to tell what exactly is supported and what isn't with these directives (@auth and @connection) and others (@function, @versioned, @searchable). What directives are supported with Aurora?

Answer (score 0):

This question would be more appropriate for the [Amplify CLI Github issues page](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues).

I would be surprised if they released support for Aurora Serverless without supporting parity in directives, but you never know.